# Firefox: Launch Applicaton recommends web app (not Open Source)

Tags: firefox, advertisements

Howto disable that "Launch Application" shows ads for web apps?

[image: I don't wish Mibbit recommendation]

Answer (score 0):

You may try some of Mozilla's troubleshooting for FireFox [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)
, Hope this helps.